# How to import excel to a table in MS SQL db through JSP page?

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp

I have google a lot but cannot find a solution. Any idea? The setup is a Tomcat with JSP handle ability running in a windows server with MS SQL server in it. This is for work and please share if you know how to do this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use apache poi for reading excel sheet into java. And later then use jdbc/hibernate to persist it to database
Hope this link will help you,
http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/